# When the regularization of a function converges by decreasing to the function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hi evryone: Let $\theta(x) $ equals $Ce^{\left( -\dfrac{1}{1-\parallel x \parallel^{2}}\right) }$ if $\parallel x\parallel<1$ and equals 0 if $\parallel x\parallel\geq 1$, where $C$ is a constant such that the total integral of $\theta =1$. Then, let $\theta_{\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{N}}\theta(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$. We know that  if $f$ is a locally integrable function on a domain $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $(N\geq 2)$, then the convolution $f\star \theta_{\varepsilon}$ converges ultimately to $f$ almost everywhere on any open set relatively compact to $D$. My question is here: If $f$ is positive on $D$, does the convergence of the convolution decreasing? Or at least can we find a subsequence $f\star \theta_{m_{k}}$ such that for all $k$, we have
$$f(x)\leq f\star \theta_{m_{k}}(x)?$$
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly not in general. For example if $f$ is continuous and has a strict maximum at $x$ then it's clear that $f*\theta_\epsilon(x)<f(x)$.